# Practical applications of Matrix multiplication in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, matrix, mapreduce, bigdata

Recently, while learning Hadoop I encountered the problem of Matrix multiplication through Hadoop. Although I understood the idea, but just wanted to know if there are any practical situations where Matrix multiplication in Hadoop has an applications?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question intrigued me as I like maths. I suspect that it would mostly be scientific or mathematical datasets and problems that would benefit from matrix multiplication and manipulation. Have a look here for to get a feel for the type of applications that might need this: http://grids.ucs.indiana.edu/ptliupages/publications/DryadReport.pdf

Comment: Thanks Markus for your response. I liked the link that you provided as it details out various applications that can use Matrix multiplication. I guess the application is huge. :)